# Rather than have or having or to have?

Tags: grammar, verbs

MacBook is a laptop made by Apple which is designed to be slimmer each year rather than *have* / *having* / *to have* better battery life.

*Have* or *having* or *to have* - which one is correct here?

Answer (score 1):

In that sentence, I would use "to have", for parallelism with "to be slimmer". The sentence would be understandable with any of the three.

Answer (score 0):

If you use verb after "rather than", you should use either base form or ing form of the verb.
MacBook is a laptop made by Apple, which is designed to be slimmer each year rather than have (or, having) better battery life.
Note : A comma should be used before 'which' because this which-clause is a non-defining continuative relative clause.

Hope, it is clear now. Thank you.